System Settings missing after instal i386 for wine
I dont know exactly why my System Settings is missing after install i386 and wine. Unfortunately I cant using wine (because my .exe need 64bit windows) and I dont wanna use it. I notice that my system setting is missing and I cant find it. I used to Install the unity-control-center again and nothing change. If I open the unity-control-center theres only 3 settings. like this
How can I make my settings back? Maybe I can uninstall i386 but when I try it theres message that I cant remove it because can break the system.
My OS is Ubuntu 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop uses the GNOME desktop, so why unity-control-center ??  I don't understand what you hoped to achieve with that if using Ubuntu's GNOME desktop; gnome-tweaks is the GNOME tweak tool if you need more than gnome-control-center the system comes with.  You've not said where you got wine etc from; you should expect no change if you used official Ubuntu packages (from Ubuntu repositories) and not 3rd party; if you used 3rd party you should specify what exactly was done.

@guiverc THANKS! why I use unity-control-center because in any articel say that ubuntu 17 up is using it not gnome. But before it I use to check gnome-control-center and I cant install it due to problem in winehq repository. I delete my repos in source.list.d and try to install it and it works!

Ubuntu 11.04 through 17.04 used the Unity 7 desktop, at Ubuntu 17.10 and later Ubuntu Desktop returned to using the GNOME Desktop (prior to 11.04 GNOME was GNOME 2; 17.10 & later are GNOME 3 with current releases using GNOME 4).  Removing a repository will prevent new 3rd party packages from being installed, but any already installed can still cause package problems which will remain until they're removed too. For us to help, you need to specific with details (in your question please! this is a Q&A site and not a forum)  so we can help with it.

@guiverc I dont notice that, Thanks!. Yeah I will check any package after I delete the repos.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed maybe useful in the future (it easiest to remove PPA & its packages at the same time via purge)

Finally I fixed the problem.
First, When I installed wine there is no problem. I installed i386 for 32bit support. When I try to run my .exe file there is message that it needs 64bit windows. I installed 32bit wine and 64bit wine and the problem is still the same. After that I noticed the "System Settings" are missing.
I uninstalled wine and nothing changed, I tried to uninstall i386 but there is message that this process will break the system. I tried unity-control-center because in an article I read that I can use this but there is just 3 settings. I tried to install gnome-control-center but there is a problem in winehq repository (the message is missing and I cant copy it), so I tried to delete any repos in source list.d and tried to install it
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
and it works perfectly.
Now I will check the installed package because I deleted many repos in my system that maybe can make a problem later.
